# How to pin a tab in safari in osx

Tags: browser, safari

There are several options provided by other popular browsers like chrome, firefox. One of the option is to pin the tab. This feature is very handy when you wish to re-open same tabs when you restart your browser. My question is - Does safari has such feature? Or is there any plug-ins to make such feature available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never once used mac or safari in my life, but a quick google search tells me that there isn't a way to pin tabs as one would on other popular browsers.

However you can look into session managers for your purpose.
Try [SafariRestore](http://sweetpproductions.com/extensions/extensions.htm) or [Safari Pinboard](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/software/safari-pinboard-extension/).

I hope these are helpful.

Comment: Can you please tell a reason not to use Safari? Chrome suspiciously sends data to google. Firefox uses memory like hell. I feel safe & fast while browsing in safari. Add-ons & plug-ins are well tested & approved by apple. Yes. I've downloaded SafariRestore. That's better option. ;)

Comment: Actually in my experience Chrome uses more memory than firefox. Doesn't stop me from using it though. It's faster,more fluid,handles a lott of tabs very well,syncs across devices and platforms, and mainly because I've never really enjoyed using other browsers. I've tried opera, torch, midori and some more. And safari isn't there for linux, so I can't go there.
And Google could collect as much data from me as it'd like from other sources. I use a Nexus 7,moto x,gmail,google maps,google plus,google docs,google calendar,google contacts and more. Not really worried about personalized ads I am ;)

Answer (score 0):

To Pin a tab in Safari, right click over the tab you want to pin and select Pin Tab.